# Firefox drawing blank Canvas when restoring from saved base64

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, canvas, base64

I am working with a single canvas that allows the user to click on a window pane in a window image.  The idea is to show where the user has clicked.  The image will then be modified (by drawing a grill on the window) and then saved to in JPEG. I am saving the canvas image prior to the click function because I don't want the selection box to show in the final image.  However, Firefox often displays a blank canvas when restoring the canvas where IE and Chrome do not.  This works perfectly in Chrome and IE.  Any suggestions?  Does Firefox have a problem with `toDataURL()`?  Maybe some async issue going on here?  I am also aware that saving a canvas in this fashion is memory intensive and there may be a better way to do this but I'm working with what I have.

**Code:**

```
    /**
     * Restores canvas from drawingView.canvasRestorePoint if there are any restores saved
     */
    restoreCanvas:function()
    {
      var inverseScale = (1/drawingView.scaleFactor);
      var canvas = document.getElementById("drawPop.canvasOne");
      var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
      if (drawingView.canvasRestorePoint[0]!=null)
      {
        c.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = drawingView.canvasRestorePoint.pop();
        c.scale(inverseScale,inverseScale);
        c.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        c.scale(drawingView.scaleFactor, drawingView.scaleFactor);
     }
    },
    /**
     * Pushes canvas into drawingView.canvasRestorePoint
     */
    saveCanvas:function()
    {
       var canvas = document.getElementById("drawPop.canvasOne");
       var urlData = canvas.toDataURL();
       drawingView.canvasRestorePoint.push(urlData);
    },
```

**EXAMPLE OF USE:**

```
    readGrillInputs:function()
    {
        var glassNum = ir.get("drawPop.grillGlassNum").value;
        var panelNum = ir.get("drawPop.grillPanelNum").value;

        drawingView.restoreCanvas();
        drawEngine.drawGrill(glassNum, panelNum,null);
        drawingView.saveCanvas();
    },
    sortClick:function(event)
    {
      ..... //Sorts where user has clicked and generates panel/glass num
      ..... 
      drawingView.showClick(panelNum, glassNum);
    },
    showClick:function(panelNum, glassNum)
    {
       var glass = item.panels[panelNum].glasses[glassNum];
       var c = drawEngine.context;
       drawingView.restoreCanvas();
       drawingView.saveCanvas();
       c.strokeStyle = "red";
       c.strokeRect(glass.x, glass.y, glass.w, glass.h);
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

By just looking at the code setting the `img.src` is an async action to retrieve the image, so when you try to draw it 2 lines later to the canvas, it probably hasn't been loaded yet (having it in cache will make it return fast enough that it might work).

You should instead use an `img.onload` function to draw the image when it has loaded.

```
restoreCanvas:function()
{
  var inverseScale = (1/drawingView.scaleFactor);
  var canvas = document.getElementById("drawPop.canvasOne");
  var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
  if (drawingView.canvasRestorePoint[0]!=null)
  {
    c.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      c.scale(inverseScale,inverseScale);
      c.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      c.scale(drawingView.scaleFactor, drawingView.scaleFactor);
    };
    img.src = drawingView.canvasRestorePoint.pop();
 }
},
```